# Bash Cut & Sort Issue

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, awk, cut

I have a CSV with the data

```
$cat content.csv

MD5 : 1d4571a01abfbfe1a653a86109c5587f , Detection : Unknown.Trojan.Generickd , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 13
MD5 : 03f44b4a8eb4a3b88d8307452eb5b556 , Detection : Document-Word.Exploit.CVE-2012-0013 , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 0
MD5 : 58e9db1ec0fa687ee7c1510504a087c8 , Detection : Document-Powerpoint.Trojan.Vba agent , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 4
MD5 : 1d025e72e82199d1524a9249073b338d , Detection : Document-Powerpoint.Trojan.Valyria , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 1
MD5 : b3039d8f5d616c77297f0da3d5b444ea , Detection : Win32.Trojan.Dynamer , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 36
MD5 : 833ab86e5f3d915dba7eea7e79a9c11e , Detection : Win32.Virus.Sality , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 42
MD5 : 4f08e1c23ba22eb3bb1e7a7f2418f187 , Detection : Document-Powerpoint.Trojan.Valyria , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 1
MD5 : bed56264438a7da43a98073497c74f73 , Detection : DOS.Virus.Arcv , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 31
```

I want to do numerical `sort` on the 5th field ( VT Positives )  based on delimiter `","` with again all the fields ( 1 to 5 )

I tried

```
$ cut -d"," -f 1,2,3,4,5 kiran  | sort -k 5

MD5 : bed56264438a7da43a98073497c74f73 , Detection : DOS.Virus.Arcv , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 31
MD5 : 1d025e72e82199d1524a9249073b338d , Detection : Document-Powerpoint.Trojan.Valyria , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 1
MD5 : 4f08e1c23ba22eb3bb1e7a7f2418f187 , Detection : Document-Powerpoint.Trojan.Valyria , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 1
MD5 : 58e9db1ec0fa687ee7c1510504a087c8 , Detection : Document-Powerpoint.Trojan.Vba agent , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 4
MD5 : 03f44b4a8eb4a3b88d8307452eb5b556 , Detection : Document-Word.Exploit.CVE-2012-0013 , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 0
MD5 : 1d4571a01abfbfe1a653a86109c5587f , Detection : Unknown.Trojan.Generickd , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 13
MD5 : b3039d8f5d616c77297f0da3d5b444ea , Detection : Win32.Trojan.Dynamer , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 36
MD5 : 833ab86e5f3d915dba7eea7e79a9c11e , Detection : Win32.Virus.Sality , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 42

sort -t$"," -k 5 -n kiran

MD5 : 03f44b4a8eb4a3b88d8307452eb5b556 , Detection : Document-Word.Exploit.CVE-2012-0013 , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 0
MD5 : 1d025e72e82199d1524a9249073b338d , Detection : Document-Powerpoint.Trojan.Valyria , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 1
MD5 : 1d4571a01abfbfe1a653a86109c5587f , Detection : Unknown.Trojan.Generickd , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 13
MD5 : 4f08e1c23ba22eb3bb1e7a7f2418f187 , Detection : Document-Powerpoint.Trojan.Valyria , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 1
MD5 : 58e9db1ec0fa687ee7c1510504a087c8 , Detection : Document-Powerpoint.Trojan.Vba agent , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 4
MD5 : 833ab86e5f3d915dba7eea7e79a9c11e , Detection : Win32.Virus.Sality , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 42
MD5 : b3039d8f5d616c77297f0da3d5b444ea , Detection : Win32.Trojan.Dynamer , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 36
MD5 : bed56264438a7da43a98073497c74f73 , Detection : DOS.Virus.Arcv , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 31
```

Tried multiple combinations , It doesn't work as expected. Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sort -t"," -k 5.15 -n file
```

The delimitier is set to the comma (and no need for `$` before the string).

The key to perform the numerical sort is the 5th field starting from the 15th character (length of `VT Positives` string).

As said in the `sort` man page:

> KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where F is a field number and C a character position in the field

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks

Comment: Nice! Definitely the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

As the key to be sorted is the last part of the whole line, you can copy that in front of the line, sort it and finally strip it off again:

```
awk '{print $NF, $0}' kiran | sort -g | sed 's/^[0-9]\+//'
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove 'VT Positives', sort, put it back again :

```
$ sed 's/, VT Positives / , /g' content.csv | sort -t, -n -k 5 | sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\)$/VT Positives \1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sort -k17 -n kiran
```

Output:

```
MD5 : 03f44b4a8eb4a3b88d8307452eb5b556 , Detection : Document-Word.Exploit.CVE-2012-0013 , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 0
MD5 : 58e9db1ec0fa687ee7c1510504a087c8 , Detection : Document-Powerpoint.Trojan.Vba agent , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 4
MD5 : 1d025e72e82199d1524a9249073b338d , Detection : Document-Powerpoint.Trojan.Valyria , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 1
MD5 : 4f08e1c23ba22eb3bb1e7a7f2418f187 , Detection : Document-Powerpoint.Trojan.Valyria , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 1
MD5 : 1d4571a01abfbfe1a653a86109c5587f , Detection : Unknown.Trojan.Generickd , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 13
MD5 : bed56264438a7da43a98073497c74f73 , Detection : DOS.Virus.Arcv , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 31
MD5 : b3039d8f5d616c77297f0da3d5b444ea , Detection : Win32.Trojan.Dynamer , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 36
MD5 : 833ab86e5f3d915dba7eea7e79a9c11e , Detection : Win32.Virus.Sality , Level : 5, Factor : 5, VT Positives 42
```

- -**k #** - this argument specifies the first column that will be used to sort. (note that column here is defined as a whitespace delimited field; so `k17` is used)

Comment: This didn't sort properly again. If you see the result , VT positives 0 is first and 4 is second.

Comment: One of the fields inside comma-delimiters has spaces, that's whey this way of counting the fields doesn't work.